# Importing DMP file into oracle 10g xe

Tags: oracle

I exported backup file of user hr By using this command

```
exp hr/usman file=c:\backup\hr.dmp owner=hr
```

Now I am importing dmp file into oracle 10 express edition after importing dmp file tables are not showing in user or schema.

[image]

```
imp system/sys file=c:\backup\hr.dmp fromuser=hr touser=hr
```

Comment: Can you share the output of the logfile of the export and verify how many tables to exported during the export session? Also share the logfile output of the import session. and since you did not specify log parameter orignially that means for this you have to do the export import again with the log parameter set (pls. check documentation on it) and then rerun both export and import and share the output. also before doing this , check the output by **select * from tab** Thanks.

Comment: A more detailed test case would shed more light on this. Export one test table, showing us the Oracle version, exp version, exact command you used and all the output. Then do the same for an import.

Comment: I didn't export log file I just simply exported dmp file